# How to install RedisJSON on existing RedisLabs instance

Tags: redis, redisjson, redislabs

I have a (paid) redis-labs instance. how can I use redis-json features on top of it?

Also, can I use normal redis-commands in a redis which has redis-json module installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you are using Redis Enterprise or Redis Enterprise Cloud

- Redis Enterprise Cloud: https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rc/databases/create-database/
- Redis Enterprise: https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/modules/add-module-to-database/

or follow this quickstart: https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/modules/redisjson/redisjson-quickstart/

> Also, can I use normal redis-commands in a redis which has redis-json
> module installed?

Yes, all Redis commands will be available (RedisJSON extends Redis)